# Entity Framework | How to get an entity if it has two separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a table of [shows] and table of [genres],

and many-to-many table like that:

```
+-------+--------+
|showId | genreId|
+-------+--------+
| 1     |      1 |
| 2     |      1 |
| 2     |      2 |
| 4     |      1 |
+-------+--------+
```

I want to get shows that have specified genres ids, not just one id.

-for example: I want all shows that have the genre Id 1 and 2, so result would be => show Id 2

I'll appereciate if someone explain how to do it by entity framework (I'm using repository pattern if that helps).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using code first, you should have a Genres collection on Show

so you'd basically do:

```
var shows = context.Shows.Where(x => x.Genres.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(1) && x.Genres.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(2)).ToList();
```